# Need Help DRYing things up - Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, view, haml, dry

```
.row
    .nine.columns.centered
        %ul.bucketlist

            - @buckets.each_with_index do |resource, index|
                %a{:href => "#{bucket_path(resource)}"}
                    %li.bucket
                        %h4= index + 1
                        %h5= resouce.name

            %a{:href => "#{new_bucket_path}"}
                %li.bucket.empty
                    = image_tag "add.gif"
                    %h5 Add Bucket
```

I have the above code written in 3 different views, with only minor differences between them. This doesn't seem very DRY to me, so I'm looking for some help to clean this up.

Between the views only a few things vary:

1. `@buckets.each` - The `@buckets` collection needs to change between `@notes`, `@units` aswell.
2. `#{bucket_path}` - I'd like to be able to pass in a variable so that bucket_path becomes resource_path.

If anyone can offer any help, it'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My experience with haml is limited, but I think you should be able to put the common code into a partial (a file named `_common.html.haml`, for instance), and then in the view simply do:

```
= render 'common', :items => @buckets, :new_item_path => new_bucket_path
```

Then change the partial like this:

```
%ul.bucketlist
    - items.each_with_index do |resource, index|
        %a{:href => url_for(resource)}
            %li.bucket
                %h4= index + 1
                %h5= resouce.name

    %a{:href => "#{new_item_path}"}
        %li.bucket.empty
            = image_tag "add.gif"
            %h5 Add Item
```

Comment: Looks good, but having a problem passing the path into the Partial.
I need to output the path as bucket_path(bucket), so how would I send this to the partial?

Comment: Maye you can drop the path argument alltogether by using the url_for helper instead? `url_for(resource)` should give you the correct url for each item.

Comment: Excellent Idea :D It's all working now, except I don't know how to pass the new_resource_path into the partial (the new_resource_path) is outside of the .each block?

Comment: The same as in the for the :path above, just pass in `:new_item_path => new_bucket_path` in your view, and reference `new_item_path` in place of `new_bucket_path` in the partial. I updated the answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

- One solution could be writing a helper function to generate the html.
  People typically don't like html in helpers, but in this case it
  would be a good idea. Write a function where you pass in the resource
  name and it generates this code for you
- Another way is to check the controller you are in and generate the required code based on that. For instance

  > resource = @buckets if params[controller]=='bucket'

  A more condensed way to remove if statements would be something like following, but i havnt tried it out.

  > exec "resource = @#{params[:controller]}s"

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: I like the idea of a helper function, but am not entirely sure how to do this.

Aside from nesting the strucutral HTML within the content_tags, how would I go about recreating the anchor and it's children?